# Extjs model load gets error "Invalid record id returned for" but only when fired from global controller

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, model

In my Extjs app I have a model:

```
Ext.define('Registration.model.SessionDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', mapping: 'recid'}, // showing this field to show that an id field is being specified
        ...
    ],
    proxy:{
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'sessions',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'record'
        }
    }
});
```

When I load a specific record in this model via the proxy anywhere but my global controller it loads successfully:

[image: Example from javascript console]

But when I try to fire this from my global controller:

```
onSessionDetailNavigation: function (sessionsId){
    // where session id is 43149 passed in from my router
    var detailsWindow = Ext.widget('sessiondetails');
    var model = Registration.model.SessionDetails;

    var session = model.load(sessionsId, {
        callback: function (){
            console.log('callback fired');
        }
    });

    ...
```

The network call is made and returns successful from my API:

[image: Network call from global controller]

I get the error:

> Invalid record id returned for 43149@Registration.model.SessionDetails

I didn't think running this in the global controller scope would have any affect on the model record loading. What am I missing here?

## Update

Here's the result of trying to get the model via the ModelManager:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and after I changed the ID to explicitly be set to an `int` it didn't throw an error anymore.

```
{
    name : 'id',
    type : 'int',
    mapping : 'recid'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `onSessionDetailNavigation` try

```
var session = new Registration.model.SessionDetails();
//or
var session = Ext.create('Registration.model.SessionDetails');

session.load(sessionsId, {
    callback: function (){
        console.log('callback fired');
    }
});
```

or

```
var session = Ext.create('Registration.model.SessionDetails', {
    id: sessionId
});

session.load();
```

Comment: So I gave both of those a try. In each case it changed the network request. It's still firing a get request, but instead of using the restful `mydomain.com/entity/recordid` syntax it's firing with the name of the model in place of the id: `http://registration.ssc.dev/sessions/Registration.model.SessionDetails-1?_dc=1443125707197`.

Comment: And the proxy is definitely still rest. `session.getProxy().type` while paused in the debugger after creating the model class outputs `rest`, so I would think the load method should append the id to the end of the uri like it was before :/ I'm not sure why it's not now.

Comment: What if you use `var session = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Registration.model.SessionDetails');` and load it?

Comment: I get a ` Ext.data.ModelManager#getModel" is deprecated.` error with that one :/

Comment: But does it load? It's just to get a reference ;)

Comment: Ah, no it throws the error and then gives me a console trace. The network request never fires. I'll update the question with a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had implemented a servlet that everytime returns a list of objects.
But in background (on click) ext was doing a request with the record id as parameter expecting to receive a single result. As the request returned a list, ext tryed to use the first record of the list comparing the id (explain the fact that generaly the first line in grid dont result error message) and as the id selected on my grid wasn't equal the first id returned is crashed (invalid id returned). The solution for me was to test if the request contained an id parameter and, in affirmative case, the servlet returns only the record with the id requested instead of a list of varios records.
Hope that helps.
Sorry for the english...